# How to draw this type of multi-segment error graph?

Tags: plotting

As you can see, there are multiple 'y-axes,' and they share a single y-axis and x-axis.
[image]

As suggested by the comments, I used the PlotGrid resource function

```mathematica
PlotGrid = ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"];

SetOptions[
  Plot,
  Frame -> {False, True, False, False},
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick],
  Axes -> False
  ];

plot1 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
plot2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
plot3 = Plot[x, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> {True, True, False, False}];
PlotGrid[
 {
  {plot1},
  {plot2},
  {plot3}
  },
 Spacings -> Scaled@0.03]
```

[image]

The following question is this, I don't know how to describe, graphically show

[image]

Comment: Check document of `ListPlot`, particularly `Options` -> `PlotLayout` section. And you'll find more by searching `PlotLayout` in this site. See also: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid

Comment: @xzczd Thank you very much for your suggestion. I have already drawn the axes, but I'm not sure how to draw the shared y-axis on the right side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using "Inset" like:

```
Graphics[{Arrow[{{0.01, 0}, {0.01, 1}}], 
  Inset[PlotGrid[{{plot1}, {plot2}, {plot3}}, Spacings -> Scaled@0.03]
   , Scaled[{0.1, 0.04}], {0, 0}, {1, 1}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]